# Unable to delete duplicate record in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, delete-row

While inserting records through windows form, I accidentally inserted a record twice because it wasn't reflected in the data grid view which is present in the form itself. Now I am unable to delete that duplicate record. I tried to add unique key but that operation failed because of that duplicate row. I tried to set the primary key as well but that operation also got failed. And I can't delete it from the table manually. The error message is as follows:

> Error Source: Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataTools.
>   Error Message: The row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(2 rows).

How can I update or delete that row?

Comment: why are you trying to use C# to delete it, Can you just write some SQL directly?

Comment: I tried using "delete" query too. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Add the delete query you created to the question.

Comment: As an alternative you can drop and create that table

Comment: does each row have a unique identifier?

Comment: Please share your table design and sample data. You can edit your question and add that detail there.

Comment: @Joe_DM no Sir...no unique identifier.

Comment: Just run a delete query with a unique column value for the row and re-add the row again!

Comment: @ArunGeorge

Location_No | Asset_Type | Longitude | Latitude

total 161 records by now... All columns except Asset_type have NOT NULL constraint

Comment: `no unique identifier` <= that is poor design. Add an integer identity column before you do anything else and make it the primary key.

Comment: @Igor I cannot add unique identifier at this stage as there is a duplicate row.

Comment: @SurajS I've tried that...neither I can update the row nor can delete it

Comment: @RitujaNashikkar - yes you can. Adding an identity column will make your duplicate record not duplicate and give you column value that you can use to delete the record with. When you add an identity column sql server can assign values for all your existing records.

Comment: Try a delete query like this `delete from <table-name> where Location_No = 'A1' and Asset_Type = 1 and Longitude = 'B1' and Latitude = 'C1'` from sql management studio. You should give the duplicate values in the query. This will delete both the rows and you can enter the correct row again. As @Igor mentioned, before you add new values, you should set an identity column or a primary key column, so that you won't face this issue again.

Comment: You can also delete both records and re-add just the one.

Comment: @Igor 
inserted new column names SERAL_NO and set its datatype to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER .but now "Post-save notification" says that "Unable to modify table. Cannot insert the value NULL intp column serial_no". I haven't even allow nulls

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is not the same as a column with type `identity`. Create a new column of type `int` and enable/turn on `IDENTITY`. Drop the column you have just created of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Comment: Thank You everyone....Finally I was able to delete the record...Now onward I would definitely add 1 more column with unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must add unique identifier as mentioned in the comments, that not should be
a big issue to do it.

after all rows has a unique identifier (for the example it will be: ID) you will be able to write a command that will delete your duplicates based on the ID that has a lower numeric value.

**An example table before executing the command:**

[image]

**Command to delete duplicates:**

```
DELETE FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID)
                  FROM   YOURTABLE
                  GROUP  BY OLD_DUPLICATE_VALUE
                  HAVING MAX(ID) IS NOT NULL)
```

**The example table after the command has been executed:**

[image]

If you intend to try it, please make sure you understand the command properly! it can be slightly dangures if you dont know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much...I tried this query but it deleted second last record...so there was a difference in ID column for the last record..so i deleted the last record too...now I don't  have duplicate record...thank you so much for your help.

Comment: anytime, glad i could help.